# google play game check for user is sign in or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-play-games, leaderboard

i have implemented google play games in my app for leaderboard.
my requirement is to display info Alert when user login first time in safari(redirect to safari automatically for login)

i have written this code

```
[GPGManager sharedInstance].statusDelegate = self;
 BOOL isSignedIn = [[GPGManager sharedInstance] signInWithClientID:kGoogleClient silently:flag];
 NSLOG(@“is signedin %d",[GPGManager sharedInstance].isSignedIn);
```

but every time `[GPGManager sharedInstance].isSignedIn` this variable returns false.

any one have any idea ??

Answer (score 0):

You must configure the [GGLContext shared instance](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in#enable_sign-in). You can do this in many places in your app. Often the easiest place to configure this instance is in your app delegate's application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method.

In your app delegate's .h file, declare that this class implements the GIDSignInDelegate protocol.

```
#import <Google/SignIn.h>
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate>
AppDelegate.h
```

In your app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`: method, configure the GGLContext shared instance and set the sign-in delegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  NSError* configureError;
  [[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError: &configureError];
  NSAssert(!configureError, @"Error configuring Google services: %@", configureError);

  [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;

  return YES;
}
```

Implement the `application:openURL:options:` method of your app delegate. The method should call the handleURL method of the GIDSignIn instance, which will properly handle the URL that your application receives at the end of the authentication process.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary *)options {
  return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                             sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                    annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
}
```

In the app delegate, implement the GIDSignInDelegate protocol to handle the sign-in process by defining the following methods:

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error {
  // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
  NSString *userId = user.userID;                  // For client-side use only!
  NSString *idToken = user.authentication.idToken; // Safe to send to the server
  NSString *fullName = user.profile.name;
  NSString *givenName = user.profile.givenName;
  NSString *familyName = user.profile.familyName;
  NSString *email = user.profile.email;
  // ...
}

- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
didDisconnectWithUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error {
  // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
  // ...
}
```